# Send an email workflow SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I created a list workflow 2013 in SPD2013 to send an email as a notification.
It is activated on item create, checks for **Date** column and if there is more than 24h till that date&time it gets to pause state. On 24h until **Date** it gets to active state again and sends an email to listed user(s) from item.

What I didn't do is that workflow sends email on Friday(s) if **Date** column is Monday(s). For now workflow is reactivated on Sunday(s) what I don't want.
Basically I want my workflow to work only on workdays, if **Date** is Monday, send email on Friday, if **Date** is Tuesday, send email on Monday, etc.
Any hint or help how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

what about using a timer job instead of workflow? You could collect the necessary data a lot easier and control the time of sending mail once a day.

Comment: Forgot to write in question, I cannot use Visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

- Create an additional column which uses a calculated Weekday Function

  =WEEKDAY([Date])
- This column outputs as number (Sunday as 1, Monday as 2 and so on)
- Using this number, you can update your condition in the workflow step.